# SignalR not dropping connections on the server

Tags: wpf, signalr, netstat

Im using SignalR 2 in WPF to retrieve scale values.
Everything works fine but Im concerned there is a bug where the connections are not getting closed properly.

If I run the cmd **netstat** on the server I can see the connections being made. After a few days of usage the connection count has grown, which is why Im wondering if there's a problem.

I've tried to identify if there's a certain scenario when the connection count grows but it all seem kinda ramdom. Sometimes connections are added and sometimes they're dropped.

The server port is 80 and the client port is random (5000+ something)

### So to the question:

Does a growing connection count as shown in netstat pose a problem?

Comment: I think connections cannot be retained by server alone, unless there is some client on the other end. So if there is a connection, a client should be complimenting it. What is your estimates about the clients accessing it?

Comment: Both the server and the clients have long uptimes and connections are being created/disposed in certain dialogs of the app. One client has around 300 connections after about 2 weeks of uptime.